# How different is “he is a voice of reason awakening the public” from “he has a voice of reason awakening the public”?

Tags: expressions, metaphors

In association with the question on Sarah Palin’s endorsement of Senator Rand Paul in the *Time Magazine* article “2013 Time 100” that I posted earlier today, I have an additional question about the expression “He is a voice of reason awakening the public” in her remark:

> “**He is a voice of reason** awakening the public to what must be done to
>   restore our prosperity and preserve the blessings of liberty for
>   future generations. His brand of libertarian-leaning conservatism
>   attracts young voters, and recently he inspired the nation with his
>   Capraesque filibuster demanding basic answers about our use of
>   drones.”

I felt somewhat uneasy with the expression, “he is a voice,” because you as an animated being can have a voice, but you cannot be a voice which is an abstract, unanimated ‘object.’

I think there are many similar (possibly metaphoric) expressions like “he is a voice of reason / a mirror of conscience / a walking encyclopedia” that are current. But is the [animated being = unanimated object] equation grammatically right as well as logically congruent?

If so, how different is “he is a voice of reason awakening the public” from “he has a voice of reason awakening the public”?

Comment: @ Yoichi: I'm partly in agreement with Andrew that it's a synedoche ("he" is personified as "a voice"). But it's worth noting that ["is **the** voice of reason"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is+the+voice+of+reason%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) occurs twice as often in Google Books as the *"**a** voice"* version. To an extent, "reason" is being metaphorically personified as something which can have "a voice".

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Or, here's another perspective.  "He is a voice of reason" contains a double--if not a triple--synecdoche.  The first is "he" and "voice"--whole to part.  The second is "voice" to "reason"--part to whole.  The third, perhaps, is the singular "a voice" and the implied and plural "many voices" (some of which by implication are unreasonable)--part to whole.  What thinkest thou?

Comment: @rhetorician: I think that's an excellent way of "deconstructing the construction". Your final step goes a long way to articulating the *tiny* difference in nuance occasioned by using **a** rather than **the**. It somewhat suggests that there are many voices - some reasonable, some unreasonable, and maybe many others that can't even be placed on that continuum. Whereas **the** is more evocative of a [Plato's Cave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave) scenario - there's just one "reason/reality" (with one "true voice"), obscured by babbling voices and other "shadowy things".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of ***synedoche***.

> Synecdoche (pron.: /sɪˈnɛkdəkiː/, si-NEK-də-kee; from Greek synekdoche (συνεκδοχή), meaning "simultaneous understanding") is a figure of speech in which a term for a part of something is used to refer to the whole of something, or vice-versa. Specifically, it is used in one of the following ways:
>
> - Part of something is used to refer to the whole thing (pars pro toto), or
> - A thing (a "whole") is used to refer to part of it (totum pro parte) (Use of the term "The Internet" to refer to the World Wide Web, which is only a part of the Internet), or
> - A specific class of thing is used to refer to a larger, more general class, or
> - A general class of thing is used to refer to a smaller, more specific class, or
> - A material is used to refer to an object composed of that material ("he wore Spandex" to refer to someone wearing pants made of Spandex), or
> - A container is used to refer to its contents. (Very common in U.S. government circles; the Defense Department being referred to by its headquarters building, e.g. "The Pentagon announced that..." used as shorthand for "The Department of Defense announced that..." or "The White House announced a new policy regarding..." rather than saying "The office of the President of the United States announced...", or "The president announced...")
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)

In this case, it's *pars pro toto*. His voice stands for him (or him using his voice).

With regard to the difference between the synecdochal *He is a voice* and the literal *He has a voice,* the use of a rhetorical device is designed to make the image stronger. All that is important is what the voice is saying.

See [John 1:23](http://bible.cc/john/1-23.htm) for what is possibly the archetypical example — which Sarah Palin almost certainly had in mind.

> He said: I am the voice of one crying out in the wilderness, make straight the way of the Lord, as said the prophet Isaiah.

Comment: Good call on John 1:23 there.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that this could be a [metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor).

(though, a synedoche seems to be a specific form of metaphor)

> All the world's a stage,
>
> And all the men and women merely players

The reason why I'm not convinced this is a *synedoche* is because I can rationalize that is it **not** "pars pro toto".

The WWW is *part of * the Internet.  Spandex refers to "pants *made of* Spandex".  But the speaker is not naturally classified as 'Reason' or its parts.  The speaker's presentation as "the voice of reason" is a metaphor.

"The voice of reason", being itself a synedoche, perhaps extends its nature to that-which-is the voice *via metaphor*.   (this is the best counter I can present to my own argument).